# applescript: GUI scripting method for toggling options (without using the mouse)

Tags: applescript

Is there any way to choose between the (format: (web archive) / (source)) in the safari "save as..." menu using something else than automator recorded mouse clicks? I'm looking for something similar to the methods you used for menu bar actions. (Using mouseclicks with automator works, but I want a more robust method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to (1) enable [Full Keyboard Access](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2840) and (2) use the `keystroke` method to send the appropriate number of <kbd>tab</kbd>s, so as to focus on the dropdown. Once it's selected you can use `keystroke` again to choose the right option.

If the item were scriptable, you would use `properties` to set how you want to do it. Since it's not, you're stuck with this uber-kludgy workaround.

Comment: Far less kludgy than the automator & mouse-click based solution that I've came up with so far. Thank you!